# php echo "%" displaying more than once

Tags: php, xpath, output, percentage

Testing with data scraping. The output I'm scraping, is a percent. So I basically slapped on a

```
echo "%<br>";
```

At the end of the actual number output which is

```
echo $ret_[66];
```

However there's an issue where the percent is actually appearing before the number as well, which is not desirable. This is the output:

```
%
-0.02%
```

Whereas what I'm trying to get is just -0.02%

Clearly I'm doing something wrong with the PHP. I'd really appreciate any feedback/solutions. Thank you!

Full code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE^E_WARNING);

include_once "global.php";

$doc = new DOMDocument;

// We don't want to bother with white spaces
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->recover = true;
$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://www.moneycontrol.com/markets/global-indices/');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$query = "//div[@class='MT10']";
$entries = $xpath->query($query);

foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    $result = trim($entry->textContent); 
    $ret_ = explode(' ', $result);
    //make sure every element in the array don't start or end with blank

    foreach ($ret_ as $key => $val){
        $ret_[$key] = trim($val);
    }

    //delete the empty element and the element is blank "\n" "\r" "\t"
    //I modify this line
    $ret_ = array_values(array_filter($ret_,deleteBlankInArray));

    //echo the last element
    echo $ret_[66];
    echo "%<br>";
}
```

Comment: "appearing before the number" and a loop (`foreach`) indicates it's likely that one of the rows is echoing nothing for `echo $ret_[66];`.

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with this? `deleteBlankInArray` Maybe try: `if ($ret_[66]) { echo $ret_[66]; echo "%<br>"; }`

Comment: Thank you Jared, I think you're right. I actually found an even easier solution, which is to just make another php file at the bottom  <?php
echo "%<br>";



?>        I shall investigate your solution however since it might be more efficient. THank you.

Comment: Yes check for `if (isset($ret_[66])) { echo $ret_[66]."%<br>"; }`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo "%<br>";



?>
```

On a seperate following PHP code. Does the same thing.

Comment: Of course it would solve the issue due to the fact that it would be executed after each and everything is executed i.e loops etc but it's not the right way to do it.Always follow proper way to code.